# SignalR and Android

Tags: android, signalr

We have a web app (not a native app) divided into a front-end and a back-end. This app is hosted on Microsoft Azure (website). We use SignalR to push notifications from the server to the client (browser).

It is working fine on PC / iOS but not on Android device. To be more specific, it is working on a Nexus 5 android 7.0 but not on a Galaxy S4 Android 4.4.2 !!

SignalR transport is set to auto (ie we dont specify the transport when we start the connection)
Anybody encountered such issue ? We don't see anything in the trace...

Thx !

Comment: Too many unclear things in your question. What SignalR implementation lib for android are you using? Some code may be?

Comment: This is a web app so I am not using any specific lib for Android, just the signalR bower component on the front end and the aspnet.signalR.core on the back end.. I am using standard signalR code to start the connection on the fron end (js) connection.start().done()... I get the connection id so the connection is established... Then from the back end, I am just getting the hubcontext using the global/connection.. And then call a client method from my server code...

Comment: Again, it is working fine with most devices... But with Android 4.4.2 it doesnt ! First I thought that it was a transport issue so i switched to serversentevents but no success...

Comment: Hope this clarifies the issue!

Comment: Have you tried another browser on your Android? SignlR uses the best transport available in the browser when set to auto.

Comment: I tried with the default browser and it works! Seems like it is not working with Chrome...

Comment: I need to look deeper in your app to give u a clean answer. However, if it's on production you can do some sort of browser sniffing (check what browser you're using) and if it's chrome force it to use long polling like so: `connection.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });`. This is just a workaround but it should help you out right now.

Comment: It did not work... I did multiple tests : on Android emulator, with Chrome installed, it works fine.. So it is really something to do with the devices. The thing is that we can reproduce the issue on most of the devices !

Comment: What r u getting in the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after some testing : I was using the request.User.Identity.Name to identify the user and calling Clients.User().someclientmethods to notify the client.

It works find on most devices but I don't know why on Android (for some versions), it was not finding the client identity name and therefore was not sending the notifications back to the client...

I had to implement a IUserIdProvider using the userId to identify the client and it seems to be working now...